# Why was the Gen'Dai homeworld destroyed?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

The [Gen'Dai homeworld](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gen%27Dai_homeworld) of the sentient [Gen'Dai](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gen%27Dai) species was attacked by the Sith Empire  prior to the Galactic War, with most of its native population killed in the fighting.

My question is why was this done?

Also if a someone could find the planet name that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the closest to an explanation we have is from the Gen'Dai known as ["The Flame"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Flame). A player-character aligned with the Sith Empire encounters him in the game [*Star Wars: The Old Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic). The encounter can be seen in a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/zMrL7bZ_9cQ?t=772).

Screenshots:

[image: The Flame quote 1]

[image: The Flame quote 2]

Transcript:

> I am Gen'Dai. My people had done nothing to your Empire when they set upon us. They tore our world apart, slaughtered our children or sold them as slaves. In fact, every species here has suffered an unprovoked attack by your Empire.

According to "The Flame", the Sith Empire attacked unprovoked simply due to a desire for conquest and perhaps to acquire slaves. "The Flame" is obviously a biased source but his claims more or less fit with the typical behavior of the Sith Empire.

Comment: Hmm. Typical anti-Sith propaganda.

Comment: @Valorum Hmmmm Sounds like what the sith emperor would say wouldnt it? :)

Comment: The Republic has very strict laws regarding religious intolerance. The Jedi are expected to uphold these laws, not break them.